# Render a children node inside its parent

Tags: nodes, routes

I'm looking for a very specific behavior. I need to display every "node's children" inside its parent. This behavior needs to be effective when the node displayed is at level 4 or below. The hierarchy is taken from the menu system.

As I am totaly stuck, any suggestion on how to do this would be really appreciated.